# Before getting started

Tags: discussion

Well this question may b a perfect fit in meta. So, I want to know a bit more about this sister site of stack overflow. I have been looking for a site like this since long, and this being a stack exchange site it just looks to be perfect. Well, So how long can a code be? is my basic questions, what are a few things to be looked into when I ask questions or put my code for review here? Is there anything programmers who review the code expect from someone who puts their code to get reviewed?

Comment: I assume you already read [the FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq), right? It doesn't answer your specific questions, but it does tell you what questions are acceptable in general.

Comment: yeah I read the FAQ, but then it confused me a little bit, so I thought its good to ask my doubt straight away!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So how long can a code be?

Reasonable. If you dump 10k lines on us nobody will look at it. Only post the necessary parts which you want to be reviewed. Normally this is done on class- or function-level, meaning you post the whole class/function you want to be reviewed and *maybe* the direct relatives (classes/functions which are directly effected by this).

> what are a few things to be looked into when I ask questions or put my code for review here?

Explain explain explain...explain what the code does, what it is supposed to do, why you think it needs review.

> Is there anything programmers who review the code expect from someone who puts their code to get reviewed?

Feedback in all variants and colors.

Comment: By "Feedback in all variants and colors." I assume you mean a) vote for any useful answer; b) add the green check to the answer that is most useful; c) a thank you comment.

Comment: @Donald.McLean: Scratch C! That's what a and b is for.